# Copy from 1 table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy from 1 table to another table on different database.

The SQL query dont seem to work:

```
INSERT INTO db1.table
  SELECT T.number, T.dob, T.house_number FROM `db2.table2` as T;
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db2.table2' doesn't exist
```

Comment: I think I can guess that *Table 'db2.table2' doesn't exist*!! Does it works without ` characters wrapping the second table name??

Comment: And are you sure that the table `table2` exists on the `db2` schema?

Comment: @OP just a note, when quoting database names and schema names you quote each individually so in this case `'db2'.'table'`.  If you specify `'db2.table'` it will look for a table named 'db2.table' on your current database which I'm sure is not the intention.  In the code examples, each ' should be treated as a backtick (`) - can't post it up properly due to the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on quoting the table name (not needed), it should be

```
FROM `db2`.`table2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
select * into dbo.test2 from dbo.test1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE recipes_new LIKE production.recipes;
INSERT recipes_new SELECT * FROM production.recipes;
```

Check out this link:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1487/copy-an-existing-mysql-table-to-a-new-table/